# Trying to display percentage in chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts

I've been trying to display the percentage on a pie chart using:

```
 var keyb = new Chart(width: 600, height: 250, theme: ChartTheme.Blue)
                .AddTitle("Distribución en el ingreso de especies")
                .AddSeries(
                chartType: "pie",
                axisLabel: "#VALX (#PERCENT)",                    
                legend: "Rainfall",
                xValue: speciesTypesNames,
                yValues: speciesQ)
                .Write(format: "png");
```

Where the xValues and yValues are `List<string>` and `List<int>` respectively. 
 But it's not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please explain what exactly "is not working"! Does not compile, unexpected result, ... ?

Comment: @NachoR can you provide more information so that we can resolve your issue? Which library or which kind to chart it is?